# delete items from a ReyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using a RecyclerView to show items. I inserted a delete Icon that is supposed to delete Items, the problem is how can i get an index of the clicked item or something to remove it from the list data structure

This is the xml code for the list:

````
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.db.passengercounting.TripDataFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".TripDataFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" />
```

Fragment item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="deleteEntry"
        android:scaleX="0.8"
        android:scaleY="0.8"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:translationY="5pt" />
</LinearLayout>
````

Comment: Please attach the adapter and viewholder classes to be able to help you

Comment: i can not post anymore code:

class MyTripDataRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private var values: List<Counting>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyTripDataRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        return ViewHolder(
            FragmentItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

Comment: override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = values[position]
        holder.idView.text = item.departureStation
        holder.contentView.text = item.fullness.toString()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = values.size

    fun updateValues( newValues: ArrayList<Counting>)
    {
        values = newValues;
    }

Comment: inner class ViewHolder(binding: FragmentItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val idView: TextView = binding.itemNumber
        val contentView: TextView = binding.content

        override fun toString(): String {
            return super.toString() + " '" + contentView.text + "'"
        }
    }
}

Comment: You can edit your question please try... @OutOfCoffeException

Comment: yes, i did. But it adds too much code

Answer (score 1):

use this in adapter

```
enter code here
ImageButton deleteButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onDeleteClick(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

and then use this in activty or fragment

```
@Override
    public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
        // Remove item from your dataset using the position
        yourDataset.remove(position);
        // Notify the adapter
        yourAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

Comment: what is the function getAdapterPosition()?